# How to add unique event listener to each of the elements

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

I am working on a laravel project. I have to iterate over a resource using the `@foreach` blade directive like so:

```
@foreach($users as $user)
    <p @click="toggleClick">{{ $user->name }}</p>
    <p v-if="clicked">Lorem ipsum</p>
@endforeach
```

You may have already noticed the problem with this approach. The problem is if there are five users, the `toggleClick` listener will be attached to each of the paragraphs. So if I click on "one" user, the hidden Lorem ipsum paragraphs will be immediately shown for "all" paragraphs. Here is an example:

> John Doe
>
> Lorem ipsum
>
> Jane Doe (Clicked)
>
> Lorem ipsum
>
> Jimmy Doe
>
> Lorem ipsum

But what I want is this:

> John Doe
>
> Jane Doe (Clicked)
>
> Lorem ipsum
>
> Jimmy Doe

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want each paragraph to behave independently, then you must have independent listeners.
For example, you could add an index in your loop and `toggleClick(event, i)` where `i` is the paragraph number.
In your HTML simply show visible paragraph using a Boolean field ;)

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap it in some div or smg like it.

```
@foreach($users as $user)
    <div>
        <p @click="toggleClick">{{ $user->name }}</p>
        <p v-if="clicked">Lorem ipsum</p>
    <div>
@endforeach
```

JS in jQ

```
q = f() ->
    $(this).parent().find('[v-if="clicked"]')
    // ...
```

Comment: Ugly but it most suitable method

Answer (score 0):

If you're not against using some classes and Javascript, I suggest you this approach:

```js
var names = document.getElementsByClassName("toggleClick");

for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
  names[i].addEventListener("click", function(index, value) {
    this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("hiddenText");
  })
}
```

```css
.hiddenText {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<p class="toggleClick">John Doe</p>
<p class="hiddenText">Lorem ipsum 1</p>
<p class="toggleClick">Jane Doe</p>
<p class="hiddenText">Lorem ipsum 2</p>
<p class="toggleClick">Jimmy Doe</p>
<p class="hiddenText">Lorem ipsum 3</p>
```

Hope it helps.